STM32F429i-Disc1 , I2C Register configuration in order to drive an LED on through pcf8574 IO-Expander
I'm writing code which configures I2C bus in STM32F429i_Disc1, first of all I configure the Clock, followed by configuring I2C1 at pins PB9 (SDA) and PB8(SCL), my I2C1 runs at a CLOCK of 45Mhz, here is my configuration:

Enable the I2C CLOCK and GPIO CLOCK
Configure the I2C PINs for ALternate Functions
a) Select Alternate Function in MODER Register
b) Select Open Drain Output
c) Select High SPEED for the PINs
d) Select Pull-up for both the Pins
e) Configure the Alternate Function in AFR Register
Reset the I2C
Program the peripheral input clock in I2C_CR2 Register in order to generate correct timings
Configure the clock control registers
Configure the rise time register
Program the I2C_CR1 register to enable the peripheral.

Explanation: during debug where I can see what happens in my registers, the Start is sent correctly, then address is recognized by slave, but the problem is that the TXE bit is set during address sending phase which is false according to Reference manual, that's why when I write the data, the BTF bit is not set, that means data doesn't not get sent, could somebody help me with this, I know my English is not very good, but I hope you understand what I meant, thanks

I opened the reference manual RM0090, TXE bit is set during adress sending is the expected behavior as per page 852, event EV8_1 in the diagram. Everything you describe looks like normal I2C behavior.
